# Use multiple launch paths to run terminal command swfit

Tags: swift, terminal, swift3

I'm trying show hidden files in Finder by running a terminal command. The problem is it looks like `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` has multiple launch paths. When I run the `which` command in terminal followed by the command I'm trying to run, it gives me three paths: `/usr/bin/defaults`, `/usr/bin/write`, and `/usr/bin/TRUE`. I can't set all three as launch paths for the command because `.launchPath` doesn't accept an array.

How can I run this command?

edit: The problem was I wasn't separating the arguments into separate strings. This code works:

```
@IBAction func showAllFiles(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/defaults"
    task.arguments = ["write", "com.apple.finder", "AppleShowAllFiles", "TRUE"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Comment: btw, [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) lets you add a button to the finder toolbar which lets you show/hide hidden files

Comment: can you add the swift code how you create the task - otherwise it looks not swift related

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `/usr/bin/defaults`. The reason you're getting this output is because the following command:

```
which defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

is like doing:

```
which defaults
which write
which com.apple.finder
which AppleShowAllFiles
which TRUE
```

which prints:

> /usr/bin/defaults
>
> /usr/bin/write
>
> (nothing)
>
> (nothing)
>
> (nothing)
>
> /usr/bin/TRUE

Comment: That's good to know. How do I run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` in Swift then?